# UiPath Error : Desktop has been disconnected while performing UI actions

Tags: ui-automation, robotics, uipath, robotic-scraping

I am using UiPath to automate some of our manual task done through website. But for some reason i get the below error. This happens when i click the link and new page gets loaded. In the new web page i try to click a button and the below error shows up.

Kindly note that i am not using RDP for automation.

"Desktop has been disconnected while performing UI actions"

> 19:03:56.3586 Error {"message":"Click 'INPUT  btnReset' : Desktop has
>   been disconnected while performing UI
>   actions.","level":"Error","timeStamp":"2017-05-05T19:03:56.3586114+05:30","windowsIdentity":"ENT\VS","processName":"TestProject","processVersion":"2017.1.6334.30035","fileName":"Seq_OptionsAtOpenCustomer","jobId":"0fd0eaaf-e7be-4ec6-83b6-09a3c2a29d96","robotName":"ENT\VS"}

Comment: Replied under my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the same error message a few days ago while I was not using RDP, with a bit research it was resolved by reverting back to an older version of the software - currently there's a bug with the latest version (2017.1.6309).

Regarding UiPath's technical support on their website, it was suggested to use 2016.2 version for now while the bug fix has not been released.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Would you know how to download the old version ? if so, can you provide the link please.

Comment: Do you know by when this bug would be fixed?

Comment: If you could not revert to old version try the beta version from here: http://download.uipath.com/beta/UiPathStudioSetup.exe